# Rails routing error No route matches [POST] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi am I trying to set up a basic form for an Article and am getting the following error when I submit the form: `No route matches [POST] "/"`

Here is the form (I know I can use form_for, but I am trying to do it without):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<% articles_path %>" method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
  <input type="text" name="body" placeholder="body">
  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resource :articles, only: [:new, :create]
  root to: 'articles#new'
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
articles_path   POST    /articles(.:format) articles#create
new_articles_path   GET /articles/new(.:format) articles#new
root_path   GET /   articles#new
```

What I don't understand is that my form action is articles_path with a post method, and the application is looking for a Post request to the root route. Shouldn't it go to my articles_path POST route?  The same thing happens when I submit the form from articles/new except it says no route POST for articles/new.

I checked other similar questions and the solution was always something to do with the form action, which I have right as far as I can tell, so I thought I'd ask my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `=` in `<% articles_path %>`. Your `<form>` tag should be:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<%= articles_path %>" method="post">
```

Without the `=`, the HTML output would have contained `action=""`, causing the form to post to the URL of the current page.

Comment: @srlrs20020 Try using `form_for` instead, you might find it a little easier in the future.